# Replace string with modified string

Tags: regex

I have a file with 1000's of rows looking like

```
"20140611","20:19","C","IT","IT","HDR","HDPDIT","675605","000000135.97"," ..........
```

I am trying to replace all occurrences of string that matches this pattern :
quote then 6 numerics followed by a closing quote ( i.e.  "675605"  with "675605@")

Using edit plus regular expression search and replace, the search string is :

```
\"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\"
```

This will find all the occurrences I need

However I'm unable construct the correct replace with reg ex to replace the match with itself followed by the @ sign e.g. "675605@

Answer (score 1):

With sed you can have:

```
sed -r 's|"([0-9]{6})"|"\1@"|g' file
```

Add `-i` to modify it inline.

So my proposed regex - replacement form is:

```
"([0-9]{6})" - "\1@"
```

Quoted:

```
\"([0-9]{6})\" - \"\\1@\"
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
\"([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])\"
```

Replacement string:

```
"\1@
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cB1vC5/1)

Replacement string would be `"\1"` if you want `"675605@"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use capturing groups. I don't know if you can use them in Edit Plus, but I think it should work:

Find what: `\"(\d{6})\"`
Replace with: `\"\1@\"`

Where `\1` is a number captured in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Open your file in vim or vi editor using below command:

## vi "filename"

then use this command it replace your "675605" pattern with "675605@"
:%s/675605/675605@/g
then
esc :wq
now you open your file it replaced all your "675605" pattern with "675605@".